# Is the extra comma grammatical?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas

This comes from The Life of John Wesley, Volume 2 by Robert Southey

> With all this, the zeal of this extraordinary man was such, **that, as he truly said of himself,** the sword was too sharp for the scabbard.

I am not sure why there's a comma between such and that. I would have personally rewrote it like this:

> With all this, the zeal of this extraordinary man was such that, as
>   he truly said of himself, the sword was too sharp for the scabbard.

Comment: This was published in 1864. I'm not completely certain, but I think it's archaic usage, which is why I looked up the publication date. I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm side-stepping the question. I think if you're trying to learn English as anything besides becoming an English scholar, this may not be all that important of a question. Also, I'd be more inclined to believe that he said that of himself if you didn't feel the need to insist it was true.

Comment: The book was first published in 1820 and so was written no later. And Southey died in 1843 so his output was sparse after that unfortunate episode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dislike saying that punctuation is part of grammar because punctuation does not even exist in the spoken language. Furthermore, what is correct punctuation varies slightly between style manuals. Finally, the so called rules of punctuation vary over time, and Southey wrote centuries ago.

Because I no longer must worry about slavish adherence to any particular style manual, my own rule is that commas should accord with what would be slight pauses if the writing was read aloud. So in this case, I would probably go with "such that" as being in accord with modern convention. But if you say the sentence aloud, the "that" is in fact somewhat separated by a very slight pause from "such." The construction "such that, as" is not at all common, and the tongue does not say it trippingly.

Answer (score 1):

To add on to Jeff Morrow's answer:

The overall language may be somewhat archaic, but I don't think the author's use of commas is particularly odd.  I, occasionally, write like this as well.  As Jeff Morrow says, commas mirror the pauses that would be there if the sentence was spoken out loud, and different authors will have a different *voice*.  It's not particularly odd or old-fashioned to add a pause between "such" and "that" in your example.

Otherwise, despite what many English students are taught, there are few (if any) immutable grammar rules for the use of commas.  Most of these refer to one or another *style guide*, which recommends a certain style for things like quotations in order to provide consistency.